# Link to directory in bash

Tags: bash, command-line

I'm using the `ln` command to create a symbolic link to a directory using bash, I went to the directory I wanted to make a link and used the following command:

```
ln -s C#/ ~/Projetos
```

This would create a link to `~/media/Projects/C#` in  the `~/Projetos` folder.

But once I `cd` to my home, the folder is displayed in red color and I can't access it, what's happening here?

[image]

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can check the link using `ls -l` (which is usually aliased to just `ll`). You will see something like this:

```
 user42@localhost$ ll ~/Projetos
 lrwxrwxrwx 1 user42 user42    3 Sep 26 19:48 Projetos -> C#/
```

this means, that using the path `/home/user42/Projetos` will be substituted with `/home/user42/C#`. This path does not exist.

You probably wanted to use either

- a correct relative link like `ln -s media/Projects/C# ~/Projetos`
- or an absolute link like in `ln -s $PWD/C#/ ~/Projetos`